# Append empty rows to Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to append empty rows (filled with np.NaN) to a pandas dataframe and currently only know how to do this using loc

```
T = pd.DataFrame(index=['a', 'b', 'c'], data={'Col0': 0, 'Col1': 1})
T
   Col0  Col1
a     0     1
b     0     1
c     0     1

missing = ['d', 'e']
for m in missing:
    T.loc[m] = np.NaN

  Col0  Col1
a   0.0   1.0
b   0.0   1.0
c   0.0   1.0
d   NaN   NaN
e   NaN   NaN
```

Do you know of a more *elegant* way to do this?

Why it is not possible to do something like

```
T.loc[missing] = np.NaN
```

thx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) by taking the [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of the current index and the missing row values:

```
In [281]:    
T.reindex(T.index.union(missing))

Out[281]:
   Col0  Col1
a   0.0   1.0
b   0.0   1.0
c   0.0   1.0
d   NaN   NaN
e   NaN   NaN
```

basically `loc` looks for the passed in labels, unfortunately [setting with enlargement](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement) only works for a single row label.

It'd be more efficient to do the above, here we take the `union` of the current index and the missing values and use these to `reindex` the df, where rows don't exist `NaN` values are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.loc` very similarly to `reindex`

```
df.loc[df.index.tolist() + missing]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a dataframe, you can use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=missing)

pd.concat([T, df])
```

Or alternatively, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=missing)

T.append(df)
```

---

Both yield:

```
   Col0  Col1
a   0.0   1.0
b   0.0   1.0
c   0.0   1.0
d   NaN   NaN
e   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Why is `name 'missing' is not defined
`

Comment: @sikisis because you didn't define it.  See OP...it has it defined as `missing = ['d', 'e']`